# Havel Hakimi Theorem -- What happens if there are no enough numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am learning about Havel Hakimi. I know how the algorithm works, but I'm not sure what happens when there are no enough numbers. For example, (2,3,3,4). I remove 4, then I'm supposed to subtract 1 from the next 4 numbers ın the sequence but there only 3 numbers. Does that mean it's not graphical, or should I subtract 1 from all the remaining numbers anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple graph of four vertices can not have a degree sequence of $(2,3,3,4)$ since that would imply the fourth vertex is of degree four... but there are only three vertices that that could have been adjacent to it... the highest degree possible in a simple graph of $n$ vertices is $n-1$ and would occur when said vertex is adjacent to all other.  (*Non-simple graphs might still have higher degrees, either as a result of parallel edges or loops*)

That you couldn't successfully perform subtracting from each of four *other* numbers here is indeed evidence that the sequence is not graphical.